# Set custom bash prompt through ssh or putty

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

When logging on to servers I would like to have time displayed on my bash prompt so when I check previous things I've done, I can see at what time I did it. I think it's a particular useful feature when trying to debug things.
It can look like this:

```
[root@server 11:46:02 ~]# ls
file1 file2
[root@server 11:47:50 ~]# whoami
root
```

I found that I kind of can do this with `ssh`:

```
ssh root@server -t "export PS1='[\u@\h $(date +%H:%M:%S) \W]\$ '; exec bash"
```

```
ssh root@server -t "export PS1='[\u@\h \t \W]\$ '; exec bash"
```

<strike>But obviously the date won't be updated each time I type something new.</strike>
I haven't figured how to do it from PuTTY at all - I see there is a setting in Connections -> Data to send Environment variables to the server, but that doesn't work.

Note that I do not want to change anything on the server side (no sshd change, no bashrc or profile change) :)

Comment: You do not to change something server sided? But how about adding a mere script? I tried around very long with this topic and also came to no solution without configuring sshd.

Comment: My reason for not wanting to change anything server side or adding scripts is I manage a great bunch of servers and it would be too inconvenient to do this. Also, I sometimes connect to servers that are not 'owned' by me and leaving scripts behind is not nice. BTW what did you try with? Putty or ssh?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot help you with putty, but note that bash has a code for the current time so you can replace `$(date +%H:%M:%S)` by `\t`.

Comment: Heey that's great! Thanks for the suggestion, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I've not actually found the answer for PuTTY, I have found a *better* alternative:
1. install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (and enjoy better productivity)
2. add Cygwin shortcut to my PATH so I can do WIN+R and type cyg to open terminal
3. add this function in Cygwin ~/.bashrc :

```
ssh () { /usr/bin/ssh "$@" -t "export PS1='[\t \u@\h \W]\$ '; exec bash"; }
```

Reopen Cygwin or `source ~/.bashrc` and `ssh user@server` and prompt is how I want it *:
`[12:03:08 user@server ~]$`

*It works on CentOS or AWS Linux. Not working on Ubuntu because it overrides $PS1.

Disclaimer: stuck on Windows, cannot install Ubuntu nor dual-boot. VM not an option. /Cry

Answer (score 0):

Not so intrusive variant for Ubuntu (just enables color prompt in remote .bashrc):

```
ssh user@server -t "sed -i 's/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g' .bashrc;exec bash"
```